# How can I include \n in this formula to substrate this text (I'm close)

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have this string contained in a mail:

```
CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE SOYA has started successfully.CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE SOYA

User
    juan.lopez@mail.com

Parameters
    output = 7
    country = 170
    period = 202204012
    DATA_REPORT_DELIVERY = NO
    read_persistance = YES
    write_persistance = YES
    client = 18277
    indicator_group = SALES


Executed tasks
```

My desired output is: `202204012`.

I use this type of formula to extract other values successfully but I didn't get why `Period` doesn't work as expected:

```
trim(first(split(last(split(body('Html_to_text'),'period = ')),'DATA')))
```

Then, my obtained output (in raw format) is:

```
"CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE SOYA has started successfully.CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE\nSOYA User juan.perez@mail.com Parameters output = 7 country = 170 period\n= 202204012"
```

While other variables such as `output` or `country` work fine and the extraction is correct. I can extract, for example, the `7`to `output` and the `170`to `country`.

With this little modification (eliminate the spaces and = sign), the output is near to the expected result:

```
trim(first(split(last(split(body('Html_to_text'),'period')),'DATA')))
```

My result obtained with this, are this:

```
= 202204012
```

[image: Perspective]

I mean. If I understand well, I should obtain the value between" `period =`  and `DATA_REPORT_DELIVERY`as the other variables.

The 'Html_to_text' raw output looks like this:

```
"body": "CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE SOYA has started successfully.CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE\nSOYA User juan.perez@mail.com Parameters output = 7 country = 170 period\n= 202204012 DATA_REPORT_DELIVERY = NO read_persistance = YES write_persistance =\nYES client = 18277 indicator_group = SALES Executed tasks
```

*I don't know how can I include the "\n" into the formula.*

Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace the `\n` for `;`. It make this so much easier.

1. I create a Compose to my Html_to_text body.
2. I replace the `\n` with this formula: `replace(outputs('Compose'),decodeUriComponent('%0A'),';')`
3. I substitute the output. Finally, I use this formula:

   `trim(first(split(last(split(outputs('Replacing'),'period;= ')),'DATA')))`

[image: It works.]